# Want to develop a windows service to serve as logger for other applications

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, enterprise-library-5

We have lot of applications running on our server that uses Enterprise Library to log. We want to develop a logging service that can serve as a common logging service all these applications can call and that way they will all be logging to a single log file and a central logger will control all the configuration. I was looking for some design solutions for what this service should look like. Should it be a windows service with a .net remoting or WCF interface exposed?

Comment: host your WCF service as Windows Service

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using .NET Remoting with an IPC channel.

Here is a tutorial/example: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_syntax/remoting/article.php/c9251/NET-Remoting-Using-a-New-IPC-Channel.htm

I've used this method for interprocess communication between several apps/services many times.

Also, have you looked into using something like log4net?  It's very powerful.

http://logging.apache.org/log4net/

I'm not too familiar with EntLib's logging code, but log4net is great.

Another option would be to just build a single shared assembly/project that all your apps utilize - that way you don't need a service running in the background, but the code is the same across all apps.

Comment: .NET Remoting? WCF is a replacement for that.  Why would you opt to use an older, legacy technology?

Comment: I am new to WCF, does it have performance impact on a system to write a WCF interface for logging as it will be called quite often. What protocol will it use?

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise Library has a Remote Logging Service that you could use: http://nuget.org/packages/EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Service/.

It was originally released with the Silverlight Integration Pack but is just a WCF service.